# slideToggle with bounce effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Every method that I have tried to create a bounce effective when my div slides up and down does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $("#div").slideToggle();
    $("#div").effect('bounce', 300);
  });
});
```

```css
div#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click</button>

<div id="div"></div>
```

Thanks for any help!

https://jsfiddle.net/zs1u8b5c/

Comment: Thanks for making it more readable lighter

Comment: I think you should try to add `id` on element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you wrote works as intended. However, as that is not part of jQuery's main API you need to include the UI script as well.

Updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1gu4u8dp/

Which would be:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

(preferably make a local copy)